# Set Azure SQL AD Admin from Azure Devops release

Tags: azure, powershell, devops

When I run the below on my local pc via powershell it completes successfully.

```
Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName -DisplayName 'AAD_GAOUAT_SQLADMIN' -ObjectId 'd9c6b5a7-079e-44b4-8911-bd0451bfb59a'
```

[image]

Now when I run the same command (via Azure Powershell) in DevOps, I get the below error

[image]

Any ideas why this fails from Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the command in devops azure powershell task, it will let you use a service connection to auth, I suppose you didn't use a correct service principal located in the correct tenant(i.e. the subscription of the sql server located).

Please follow the steps below to fix the issue.

1.In devops, navigate to the `Project Settings` -> `Service connections` -> `New service connection` -> `Azure Resource Manager` -> `Service principal (manual)`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you don't have an AD App, you can also select `Service principal (automatic)` above, then fix the values with correct information .e.g subscription. If you select `Service principal (manual)`, please make sure the service principal has an RBAC role in the subscription to set the sql server AAD admin e.g. `Owner`, `Contributor`.

2.After creating the service connection, click it and select `Manage Service Principal`.

[image]

It will open a page for the related AD App -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> add `Directory.Read.All` *Application permission* of `Azure Active Directory Graph` like below(Not `Microsoft Graph`), At last, don't forget to click `Grant admin consent for xxx` button.

This step is because `Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator` will call the AAD Graph to check the object you input, so you need to give the permission.

[image]

[image]

[image]

3.Then in the azure powershell task, select the service connection we created.

[image]

Run it, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: This was exactly the issue, thanks very much for your help!